# Company Intranet Page went down unexpectedly...HELP!

Tags: error, uls

This morning I made a minor change to the corveV4.css page and once I saved the changes, I was unable to access the page.  After roughly 2 or 3 minutes of trying to load I received an error on the page with a correlation ID.

I looked up the correlation ID in the ULS logs and this is what I found....how would I go about resolving this issue?

It reads:

High   (correlation id)    Leaving Monitored Scope   (ExecuteWcfOperation:http://Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles/GetUserData).Execution Time=9240.86146568658

High   (correlation id)  Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteOnChannel:GetUserData). Execution Time=9241.39989457265

High (correlation id) UserProfileManager.GetBulkUserProfiles() Exception:Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: Tread was being aborted. at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles. ProfilesDBCacheServiceClient. GetUserData

[image]

After refreashing the Intranet page this is the following errors I am receiving...hopefully you can read this...

[image]

Comment: If you undo the change, does the error go away? What is the exact change that you made?

Comment: no. I changed the font color for the .ms-vb a:visited and did the undo thing. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

1. Check in IIS that sharepoints application pools are started.
2. In Central Administration, Navigate to "Manage services on server" and check that "User Profile service" is started

Comment: Rob all of the SP app pools are started other than the SharePoint Web Services Root.

Comment: Good, how about the User Profile Service?

Comment: Yes the UPS is started. We have been using that for awhile. I did make a change in AD to a user extention this morning and then ran the UPS synchronization timer job in Central Admin.  Im thinking that maybe part of the issue b/c the last logs has a High item about the "UserProfiles/GetUserData.Execution Time"

Comment: Have you tried making a full sync of the user profile service? Sometimes when you change user properties it's needed to do a full sync

Comment: I just completed a full sync. It didnt fix anything. Could I just created a new UPS application? I think the UPS app that was created before I joined the company a few months ago was not set up correctly.

Comment: Please check the thinkgs noted in http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/02/22/no-user-profile-application-available-mystery-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx and http://kgraeme.wordpress.com/2010/09/23/userprofileapplicationnotavailableexception-in-sharepoint-2010/ (but I'm not totally convinced that the problem in in the UPS, since your last screenshot shows no errors)

Comment: I created a new UPS application and it allowed me to open the page. Thanks for your help Rob!

Comment: Sweet! Just glad I could help you out, or at least point you in the right direction